# What is the MOD value when OR is given?

Tags: formula

What's the value we get when `MOD` and `OR` Is given 
for exmple: `OR(Count_c=0,MOD(Count_c,2)<>0)`?

Answer (score 4):

That formula yields true when `Count__c` is 0 or any odd number.